# Echo certain pieces of text only if a value is filled in

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, echo

guys, I'm new in the whole php thing and I'm mot familiar with the terminology and all the functions and such.
I believe what I am asking here is super simple to do, I just wasn't able to find it anywhere.

In the code below, you guys will notice that not all the fields show in every change of the dropdown menu TYPE, and, of course they don't, that's the whole point. I mean, I have arranged for each TYPE to have it's own fields. The thing is: how can I adapt for the html ECHO code to show ONLY the "labels" (let's call what I'm putting in bold in e.g.: . "< b r />**Preview the Task:**" . $row['taskpre']) and all the similar elements that), I mean, the pieces of HTML in the while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)), for the fields that were filled in? I mean, I don't want that in RESULT there are the "labels" of the fields whose values are there.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","activitytest1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO activitytest1 (type, author, taskpre, taskdescription, outcome, semipre, semiwhile, exercisedescription, practicepre, practiceinstructions, leadin, gamepre, gameinstructions, videopre, videowhile, videopost, songpre, songwhile, songpost, mimioinstructions, otherinstructions, path, books, grouping, time)
VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssssssssssssssss', $type, $author, $taskpre, $taskdescription, $outcome, $semipre, $semiwhile, $exercisedescription, $practicepre, $practiceinstructions, $leadin, $gamepre, $gameinstructions, $videopre, $videowhile, $videopost, $songpre, $songwhile, $songpost, $mimioinstructions, $otherinstructions, $path, $books, $grouping, $time);

$type = $_POST['type'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$taskpre = $_POST['taskpre'];
$taskdescription = $_POST['taskdescription'];
$outcome = $_POST['outcome'];
$semipre = $_POST['semipre'];
$semiwhile = $_POST['semiwhile'];
$exercisedescription = $_POST['exercisedescription'];
$practicepre = $_POST['practicepre'];
$practiceinstructions = $_POST['practiceinstructions'];
$leadin = $_POST['leadin'];
$gamepre = $_POST['gamepre'];
$gameinstructions = $_POST['gameinstructions'];
$videopre = $_POST['videopre'];
$videowhile = $_POST['videowhile'];
$videopost = $_POST['videopost'];
$songpre = $_POST['songpre'];
$songwhile = $_POST['songwhile'];
$songpost = $_POST['songpost'];
$mimioinstructions = $_POST['mimioinstructions'];
$otherinstructions = $_POST['otherinstructions'];
$path = $_POST['path'];
$books = $_POST['books'];
$grouping = $_POST['grouping'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];


mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM activitytest1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table width='909' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th width='125' scope='col'>Type</th>
<th width='680' scope='col'>Description</th>
<th width='120' scope='col'>Author</th>
</tr></table>

<br/>

<table width='909' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td width='125'>" . $row['type'] . "</th>
<td width='680'>Time:" . $row['time'] . " min. <br><br>" . $row['books'] . "<br/>Grouping: " . $row['grouping'] . "<br/>Preview the Task:" . $row['taskpre'] . "<br/>Instructions:" . $row['taskdescription'] . "<br/>Outcome:" . $row['outcome'] . "<br/>Preview the semi-task:" . $row['semipre'] . "<br/>Instructions:" . $row['semiwhile'] . "<br/>Exercise Instructions: " . $row['exercisedescription'] . "<br/> Preview the Practice:" . $row['practicepre'] . "<br/>Practice Instructions:" . $row['practiceinstructions'] . "<br/>Lead-in:" . $row['leadin'] . "<br/>Preview the Game:" . $row['gamepre'] . "<br/>Game Instructions:" . $row['gameinstructions'] . "<br/>Song PRE:" . $row['songpre'] . "<br/>Song WHILE:" . $row['songwhile'] . "<br/>Song POST:" . $row['songpost'] . "<br/>Video PRE:" . $row['videopre'] . "<br/>Video WHILE:" . $row['videowhile'] . "<br/>Video POST:" . $row['videopost'] . "<br/>Mimio Instructions:" . $row['mimioinstructions'] . "<br/>Instructions:" . $row['otherinstructions'] . "<br/><br>Link/Path" . $row['path'] . "<br/></th>
<td width='120'>" . $row['author'] . "</th>
</tr></table> <br/> <hr size='1'/>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th width="125" scope="col">Type</th>
<th width="680" scope="col">Description</th>
<th width="120" scope="col">Author</th>
</tr></table>
<br>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">

<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<td width="125"><label>

</label>
<select name="type" id="type" onChange="display(this,'Task','Semi-task','Practice','Exercise','Lead-in', 'Game', 'Video','Song','Mimio','Other');">
<option value="Unselected" selected="selected">Choose one:</option>
<option value="Task">Task</option>
<option value="Semi-task">Semi-task</option>
<option value="Practice">Practice</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
<option value="Lead-in">Lead-in</option>
<option value="Game">Game</option>
<option value="Video">Video</option>
<option value="Song">Song</option>
<option value="Mimio">Mimio</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select></td>
<td width="680"><div id="Task" style="display:none"> Task: <br />
Lead-in/Preview the task: <textarea name="taskpre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Instructions: <textarea name="taskdescription" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Outcome: 
<textarea name="outcome" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
</div>

<div id="Semi-task" style="display:none">Semi-task:<br />
Lead-in/Preview the task: <textarea name="semipre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Instructions: <textarea name="semiwhile" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
</div>

<div id="Exercise" style="display:none">Exercise:<br />
Instructions/Obs.: 
<textarea name="exercisedescription" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="Practice" style="display:none">
Practice:<br />
Lead-in/Preview the task: <textarea name="practicepre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Instructions: <textarea name="practiceinstructions" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
</div>

<div id="Lead-in" style="display:none">
Lead-in:<br>
<textarea name="leadin" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea><br>
</div>
<div id="Game" style="display:none">
Game:<br />
Lead-in: 
<textarea name="gamepre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Instructions: <textarea name="gameinstructions" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="Video" style="display:none"> Video: <br />
Pre: <textarea name="videopre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
While: <textarea name="videowhile" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Post: 
<textarea name="videopost" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="Song" style="display:none"> Song: <br />
Pre: <textarea name="songpre" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
While: <textarea name="songwhile" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
<br />
Post: 
<textarea name="songpost" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="Mimio" style="display:none">Mimio:<br />
Instructions:<br>
<textarea name="mimioinstructions" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="Other" style="display:none">Other:<br />
Instructions:<br>
<textarea name="otherinstructions" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea><br />
</div> </td>
<td width="120"><input name="author" type="text" size="12" maxlength="25" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<select name="books" id="Books">
<option value="books open" selected="selected">books open</option>
<option value="books closed">books closed</option>
</select>
<br />
<select name="grouping">
<option value="individual" selected="selected">individual</option>
<option value="pairs">pairs</option>
<option value="trios">trios</option>
<option value="groups of 3 to 4 students">groups of 3 to 4 students</option>
<option value="groups of 5 students">groups of 5 students</option>
<option value="divide the class into 2 groups">divide the class into 2 groups</option>
<option value="divide the class into 3 groups">divide the class into 3 groups</option>
<option value="divide the class into 4 groups">divide the class into 4 groups</option>
</select>
<br />
about 
<input name="time" type="text" id="Time" size="1" />
min </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Link/Path: <input name="path" type="text" id="Path" size="40" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post!" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

P.S.: The page is a dropdown menu that, having each one of its options selected, will change the fields that show in the page.
I mean, when I select "Video" in the dropdown menu, it shows the fields - which are textareas: "videopre", "videowhile", and "videopost". If I select "Exercise", though, the only field it shows is "exerciseinstructions".

So, I want that this piece of HTML "`"<br/>Preview the Task:"`" only shows if the value . $row['taskpre'] is filled in, and so forth, for all the oether ones. Otherwise, I don't want that the `"<br/>Preview the Task:"` echoes with the rest of the code, ok?

This is the ECHO that I get when I submit a "Task" (the task values are: 'taskpre', 'taskdescription' and 'outcome'):

http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm177/JuniorCodi/php_zps5ca6aa90.png

In the picture above I marked with a check what I want to echo and what's in red is what I don't want to echo when I select TASK.

I am a total newbie at this and I don't know if an IF statement would work inside a WHILE statement (at least when I tried there were errors).
Can anyone help me by giving me a sample of how this code would be?

Comment: *"guys, I'm new in the whole php thing and I'm mot familiar with the terminology and all the functions and such"* - And you're jumping "in the deep end" right away. You should learn to swim before you can dive off an Olympic-sized swimming pool. At the very least, the *"dog paddle".*

Comment: *"In the picture above I marked with a check..."* - Like I have a PhotoBucket account so I can view that file. **NO-GO**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($row['taskpre']) {
   //your echo here
}
```

or with php tags:

```
<?php if($row['taskpre']) : ?>
   <your_html_here>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And please do not post all your code in the next question unless you referr to all of it. :)

**EDIT**

In your special case:

```
echo "..." . ($row['practicepre'] ? "<br/> Preview the Practice:" . $row['practicepre'] : "") . "<br/>Practice Instructions:" . "...";
```